# Order of operation and How does the random() play in this scenario

Tags: javascript, loops, random, let, floor

Just started learning loops and I'm having trouble understanding the order of operation here in the let value, along with how the random() works in this scenario.

From what it looks like: Math.floor() prevents decimals and Math.random() selects a random number between 0 and 36. Does random() select a random value for both MAX and MIN? Does random() also generate a random for its self to be multiplied by whatever the value of MAX and MIN equal after being subtracted, then adding the MIN back?

```
const MIN = 0;
const MAX = 36;
var testNumber = 15;
var i = 1;

while (MAX) {
    let randomValue = Math.floor(Math.random() * (MAX - MIN)) + MIN;

    if (randomValue == testNumber) {
        break;
    }
```

Answer (score 2):

Math.random() provides a random floating point number between 0 and 1. If you want to get a wider range of random values, you multiply by the magnitude of the range you want (i.e. MAX - MIN). Then, if MIN is great than 0 you'll need to add it to the resulting random number, otherwise the results range would be 0 up to (MAX - MIN).

As you say, Math.floor() simply rounds the result down to the nearest integer.

Answer (score 0):

The `Math.floor()` function returns the largest integer *less* than or equal to a given number. This is in contrast to the `Math.ceil()` function that returns the largest integer *more* than or equal to a given number.

The `Math.random()` function returns a floating-point, pseudo-random number in the range 0 to less than 1 (inclusive of 0, but not 1) with an approximately uniform distribution over that range — which you can then scale to your desired range.

So in the case of your `randomValue` variable, a pseudo-random value between the values for MIN and MAX is generated. This value could have decimals because of how `Math.random()` operates thus `Math.floor` is used to get a whole number. MIN is added to the end so that the random value will always fall within the range, especially if MIN is not 0.

Comment: So basically its picking a random number for MAX and MIN and subtracting the MIN then re-adding the MIN? For instance: MAX = 22 MIN = 15 So 22 - 15 + 15? and its result is 22? –

Comment: If `Math.random() = .05` and `MIN = 0` and `MAX = 36` then `Math.floor(.05 * (36 - 0)) + 0 = 1`. If `Math.random() = .05` and `MIN = 3` and `MAX = 36` then `Math.floor(.05 * (36 - 3)) + 3 = 4`. If we didn't add 3 at the end then the answer would be 1 which falls below the minimum value of 3.